# validation of select option in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am using select option through Struts HTML tags for a particular jsp. The values of the option are Yes and No. Here is the code.

```
  <select name="select" id='choice'>
     <option value="<%YES%>" selected><%="YES"%></option>
     <option value="<%=NO%>"></option>
```

The value seen in the select option list by default will be YES. 
I am performing validation such that if no value is selected(as Selected property given on 'YES') and form is submitted, a alert should be thrown to select new value. Below is my code.

```
 if( document.form.select.value == "YES" )
 {
   alert( "Please select other value" );
   return false;
 }
 if( document.form.select.value == "NO" )
 {
   alert( "Please select other value" );
   return false;
 }
```

The above code is not validating properly. Can anyone suggest me some changes.
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, when the form is submitted you're always going to ask the user to choose the other value, reguardless of what they have selected.

Comment: I like to validate the user input in such a way that if the user selects the same value without changing the value(without selecting other value) a error should be thrown. I am unable to do the validation. could you please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to check if the selected value is the default value, even though I am not understanding very well your intentions.

```
el = document.getElementById('choice');

if( el.options[el.selectedIndex].defaultSelected){
    alert("Please select other value");
    return false;
}
```

PS: you probably need to fix your code :

```
<select name="select" id='choice'>
     <option value="<%=YES%>" selected><%="YES"%></option>
     <option value="<%=NO%>"></option>
</select>
```